# swift table view controller is not scrollable

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code:

```
class PlayersNamesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var players = [Player]()
    let numberOfPlayers = 30
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       loadPlayers()
    }
    func loadPlayers(){
        for index in 0..<numberOfPlayers{
            let player = Player(name: "Player \(index)")
            players += [player]
        }
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return players.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playerCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let player = players[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(player.name)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

in my storyboard, i select `Basic` for the style of the cell.

My problem is that the table view is not scrollable, i just can see the first 14 players, like this:

[image]

#### Update 1

I put `print("\(indexPath.row)")` on the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` method and I can see that there are just 15 values being printed, where are the other 30?

#### Update2

Scroll is enabled on the table view
[image]

#### Update3

User Interaction is enabled, as u see here

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think what you need is a uinavigation controller, and you will be fine

Comment: @Lamar absolutely not, check my update to see, there are just 15 elements being printed, where are the other 15?

Comment: What I am saying is to embed your tableview with a uinavigation controller.

Comment: @Lamar thanks for your suggestion, but I believe that the problem is in somewhere else. That is because i see just 15 items are being printed on the console. That means the method is not being called for the 30 items.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli UITableView does not load all data in one go, it reuses cells as and when the user scrolls through the TableView.

Comment: @Santhosh so, back to the main question, why it is not scrolling? :(

Comment: I embed the table view controller in a UI navigation controller, but still not scrollable yet :( :( :X :( :X :(

Comment: where are you swift giants ?!

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Your code seems to be fine. Check to see if 'scrolling enabled' is checked for the ScrollView in TableView in Storyboard.

Comment: @Santhosh yes it is enabled, I updated my question adding a picture to prove that

Comment: with Android, millions would have helped, but here, just 25 views after two hours and a half of posting the question

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Patience my friend. Select the tableview and under "View" in Attributes Inspector check to see if 'user interaction enabled' is checked.

Comment: @Santhosh yes it is enabled, I added an image as a prove

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli did you add layout constraints to your tableview?

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren no I didn't

Comment: Please try to add auto layout constraints to your table view. Sometimes it causes some UI errors.

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren what constrains please? the UITableViewControlelr doesn't have anything except the tableview and the cell, which comes when you drop the UITableViewController from the object library. I don't thing the problem is with the constrains at all. there is something hiding in this question :( :(

Comment: Select your tableView in storyboard. Then, at the bottom of storyboard screen, there will be a Pin button. Click it. In the popup opened, unselect Constraints to Margins and add some layout constraints (for example top, bottom, left, right all equal 0)

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren my friend, i believe the problem is not from the constrains, if you have another idea, i will be listening. thanks for trying to help

Comment: Did you tried to add constraints? I had same issue with MKMapView once. I'm trying to help. If you haven't tried to do what I say, I can't help anymore.

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren thanks for your trying, let me wait for another user then. Thank you very much

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can't see the all 30 values because this method only called 15 times. When you scroll you'll see other 15 values. Main issue here is tableView not enabled. As I said, I had same issue with mapview and when I didn't set layout constraints, I couldn't make anything with map. After layouts it worked. This was my experience and I'm trying to help.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen someone try so aggressively to not accept help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer. Check your mouse. In simulator you should click to screen and scroll.